# how expensive are the postgres WITH RECURSIVE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have a product system that each category can have multiple subcategory layers if there aren't any products attached to them, and we can attach as many products as we want to a category if there aren't any sub-categories attached to it like the example below:

PS: I deleted other columns/constraints from the two tables for simplicity

```
      CREATE TABLE categories (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        parent_id INT
    );
    CREATE TABLE products (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        category_id serial,
        CONSTRAINT fk_category FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
    );
INSERT INTO categories (
    id,
    name,
    parent_id
)
VALUES
    (1, 'Electronic Devices', NULL),
    (2, 'lap-top', 1),
    (3, 'smart-phones', 1),
    (4, 'headphones', 1),
    (5, 'desctops', 1),
    (6, '16inc laptops', 2),
    (7, '13inc laptops', 2),
    (8, 'smart phones', 3),
    (9, 'phablets', 3),
    (10, 'wireless headphones', 4),
    (11, 'wired headphones', 4),
    (12, 'onear headphones', 10),
    (13, 'large headphones', 10);


INSERT into products (
    id, name, category_id
) VALUES 
    (1, 'mac-book-16 model 1', 6),
    (2, 'mac-book-16 model 2', 6),
    (3, 'mac-book-16 model 3', 6),
    (4, 'mac-book-13 model 1', 7),
    (5, 'mac-book-13 model 2', 7),
    (6, 'mac-book-13 model 3', 7),
    (7, 'mac-book-13 model 4', 7),
    (8, 'iphone 10', 8),
    (9, 'iphone 11', 8),
    (10, 'iphone 12', 8),
    (11, 'iphone 13', 8),
    (12, 'iphone 14', 8),
    (13, 'iphone 10 pro max', 9),
    (14, 'iphone 11 pro max', 9),
    (15, 'iphone 12 pro max', 9),
    (16, 'iphone 13 pro max', 9),
    (17, 'iphone 14 pro max', 9),
    (18, 'galegxy note 8', 9),
    (19, 'galegxy note 9', 9),
    (20, 'galegxy note 10', 9),
    (21, 'some headphones', 12),
    (22, 'samsung galexypods', 12),
    (23, 'apple earpods', 12),
    (24, 'apple earpod pro', 13);
```

Let's say I want to get all the products related to "Electronic Devices" how I'm planning to do it like below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE products_in_category AS (
    SELECT
        p.*,
        c.parent_id
    FROM
        products p
    INNER join categories c on c.id = p.category_id
    WHERE 
        category_id = 1
    UNION
        SELECT
            p2.*,
            c2.parent_id
        FROM
            products p2
        INNER join categories c2 on c2.id = p2.category_id
        INNER JOIN products_in_category s ON s.category_id = c2.parent_id
) SELECT
    *
FROM
    products_in_category limit 25;
```

I'm expecting to see all 24 rows in products, but I'm getting 0.

A: Is it possible with WITH RECURSIVE? , if it is how?

B: Is it a good way to do it this way(I do create indexes on my id fields)? is it scaleable (when we have 500 categories & 10k products for example)? if not what are the alternatives?

Comment: The more important number is the tree depth; how many nodes/parents are between the root node (category 1) and the furthest child (product); that's how many times the query will iterate.  Recursing thousands of times is an issue, recursing dozens of times is not.  An alternative is to use `nested sets`, it is optimal for finding all children of a node, but very inefficient at find any node's parent(s).  *(You're using a so called adjacency model.  Nested sets are a different model altogether and need a different database design, as well as different query approach.)*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: @MatBailie thank you so much for your help the worst case scenario would be 20 layers of nodes/parents so as you say there won't be much of a problem right?
I'm seriously expecting my select query to work can you please check it out and see why it isn't working?
also, I want to get better at database design I would be appreciated it if you could give me any suggestions.

Comment: What are your expected results from your query for the given sample dataset? (Please edit your question to include those desired results.)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You don't need a recursive query for that, just a join

Comment: @MatBailie I know, I used this query to show you want I'm expecting,
`select p.*, c.parent_id from products p join categories c on c.id = p.category_id;` 
I want to select all products that exist in all of a category's subcategories.

Comment: Please edit your question to replace those images with formatted text, before people spam downvote your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the indirect question of "why doesn't this work"...

First, you should only recurse that part of the structure that needs it; the categories in your case

- build the tree of categories first, inside the recursive CTE
- join the products to it outside of the CTE

Second, your expected results don't need a recursive query, just a join.

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  c.parent_id
FROM
  products   p
INNER join
  categories c
    ON c.id = p.category_id
```

To get all products within an arbitrary category (and its children categories)...

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  recursed_category AS
(
  SELECT
    id     AS root_category_id,
    name   AS root_category_name,
    id     AS category_id,
    name   AS category_name
  FROM
    categories

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    p.root_category_id,
    p.root_category_name,
    c.id,
    c.name
  FROM
    recursed_category   AS p  -- parent
  INNER JOIN
    categories          AS c  -- child
      ON c.parent_id = p.category_id
)
SELECT
  c.*,
  p.id    AS product_id,
  p.name  AS product_name
FROM
  recursed_category   AS c  -- category
INNER join
  products            AS p  -- product
    ON c.id = p.category_id
WHERE
  c.root_category_id = ???
```

This builds multiple trees, one for each category, and travels to every child node of each category.

Then in the `WHERE` clause you can specify which ***one*** you're actually interested in.

As SQL is Declarative, the optimiser willl apply the outer `WHERE` clause to the CTE, and ***not*** build all the trees then throw some of them away.

Then, it's the simple query again; just take the category tree and join the products on, in the outer query.

***NOTE:*** This expressly starts at a category and browses ***down***.  If you wanted to know which categories a product is in, do NOT use this.  Make your recursive CTE similarly, but start at the children and browse ***up***.  Otherwise, the optimiser ***won't*** be able to push the where clause up to the CTE.

Answer (score -1):

In this example as you can see on my Git Repos also :
https://github.com/WalterMatsuda/WITH-RECURSIVE-x-SELECT

The difference of the same operation made with a LOOP and subqueries is :
In a 1000000 Rows tables with 5 levels of hierarchy

```
For Loops and subqueries 
Query OK (execution time: 15.359 sec; total time: 15.422 sec)
For With Recursive 
Query OK (execution time: 62 ms; total time: 125 ms)
```

Both returning 1667 values .
You can try a more efficient looping logic than the most easier, but WITH RECURSIVE is made to use recursion.
Loops in other hand when you dont need to access multiple level,only want to repeat something withouth going to another conditional repetition is more efficient than Recursion.
So both should be used in their proper roles.